# How to plot the last n records of a dataframe using pandas.DataFrame.tail()

Tags: python, pandas, graph, plotly, tail

I'd like to understand this odd behaviour from tail() when it is used inside a function. Here is the data:

```
| Date                |   Open |   High |    Low |   Close |   Adj Close |      Volume |   SMA_200 |   middle_band |   stddev |   upper_band |   lower_band |      RSI |
|:--------------------|-------:|-------:|-------:|--------:|------------:|------------:|----------:|--------------:|---------:|-------------:|-------------:|---------:|
| 2022-03-09 00:00:00 | 839.48 | 860.56 | 832.01 |  858.97 |      858.97 | 1.9728e+07  |   843.345 |       856.394 |  44.6167 |      943.843 |      768.946 | 80.1658  |
| 2022-03-10 00:00:00 | 851.45 | 854.45 | 810.36 |  838.3  |      838.3  | 1.95495e+07 |   844.513 |       851.709 |  41.0356 |      932.139 |      771.28  | 46.4027  |
| 2022-03-11 00:00:00 | 840.2  | 843.8  | 793.77 |  795.35 |      795.35 | 2.22728e+07 |   845.395 |       846.249 |  40.8995 |      926.412 |      766.086 | 16.872   |
| 2022-03-14 00:00:00 | 780.61 | 800.7  | 756.04 |  766.37 |      766.37 | 2.37174e+07 |   846.072 |       841.568 |  44.4474 |      928.685 |      754.451 |  9.07682 |
| 2022-03-15 00:00:00 | 775.27 | 805.57 | 756.57 |  801.89 |      801.89 | 2.22804e+07 |   846.956 |       837.874 |  44.5258 |      925.145 |      750.604 | 57.3646  |
| 2022-03-16 00:00:00 | 809    | 842    | 802.26 |  840.23 |      840.23 | 2.80096e+07 |   848.037 |       833.764 |  39.8592 |      911.889 |      755.64  | 80.1371  |
| 2022-03-17 00:00:00 | 830.99 | 875    | 825.72 |  871.6  |      871.6  | 2.21943e+07 |   849.37  |       831.175 |  35.1321 |      900.034 |      762.316 | 89.4011  |
| 2022-03-18 00:00:00 | 874.49 | 907.85 | 867.39 |  905.39 |      905.39 | 3.34085e+07 |   851.032 |       832.627 |  37.6102 |      906.343 |      758.911 | 94.7131  |
| 2022-03-21 00:00:00 | 914.98 | 942.85 | 907.09 |  921.16 |      921.16 | 2.73272e+07 |   852.643 |       835.836 |  42.2493 |      918.645 |      753.027 | 96.3981  |
| 2022-03-22 00:00:00 | 930    | 997.8  | 921.75 |  993.98 |      993.98 | 3.52895e+07 |   854.587 |       844.458 |  54.8841 |      952.031 |      736.886 | 99.0866  |
```

Here is one way of plotting it:
import plotly.express as px
ticker = 'TSLA'

```
def boll(ticker,points):
    colours = ['steelblue', 'tan', 'black', 'red', 'green']
    fig = px.line(df.tail(points), x=df.tail(points).index, y=['middle_band', 
          'SMA_200', 'upper_band', 'lower_band','Close'], title=f'{ticker}', 
          color_discrete_sequence=colours, width=800, height=600)
    fig.update_traces(textfont_size=12, showlegend=True)
    fig.update_layout(legend=dict(
        yanchor="top",
        y=0.9,
        xanchor="left",
        x=0.02
     ))
     fig.update_xaxes(title_text='Price evolution over time',  title_font = {"size": 
                     16},)
     fig.update_yaxes(title_text='Price', tickprefix="$")
     fig.show()

boll(ticker,10)
```

To obtain this:
[image: Graphic of Tesla's last 10 close prices]

But if I try to use tail() in a function I get a funny scale as if the first records of the entire dataframe (going back to 2015 and not provided here to keep sample small) are considered to determine the scale. (Thanks to Derek Banas for a great part of this code).

```
def plot_with_boll_bands(df,points,ticker,plot):

fig = go.Figure()

candle = go.Candlestick(x=df.tail(points).index, open=df['Open'],
high=df['High'], low=df['Low'],
close=df['Close'], name="Candlestick")

upper_line = go.Scatter(x=df.tail(points).index, y=df['upper_band'], 
line=dict(color='rgba(250, 0, 0, 0.75)', 
width=1), name="Upper Band")

mid_line = go.Scatter(x=df.tail(points).index, y=df['middle_band'], 
line=dict(color='rgba(0, 0, 250, 0.75)', 
width=0.7), name="Middle Band")

lower_line = go.Scatter(x=df.tail(points).index, y=df['lower_band'], 
line=dict(color='rgba(0, 250, 0, 0.75)', 
width=1), name="Lower Band")

mavg_line = go.Scatter(x=df.tail(points).index, y=df['SMA_200'], 
line=dict(color='rgba(119, 136, 153, 1)', 
width=1), name="Moving Avg 200d")

close_line = go.Scatter(x=df.tail(points).index, y=df['Close'], 
line=dict(color='rgba(5, 5, 5, 1)', 
width=1), name="Close Price")

fig.add_trace(candle)
fig.add_trace(upper_line)
fig.add_trace(mid_line)
fig.add_trace(lower_line)
fig.add_trace(mavg_line)
fig.add_trace(close_line)

fig.update_xaxes(title="Date", rangeslider_visible=True)
fig.update_yaxes(title="Price")

fig.update_layout(title=ticker + " Bollinger Bands",
height=1200, width=1800, showlegend=True)
if plot == 'y':
    fig.write_image(PATH + ticker + "bollinger.png")
fig.show()
```

Calling the function:
plot_with_boll_bands(df,10,'TSLA','y') #To get 10 last records
When plotting we get:
[image: Tesla last 10 close prices plot]
Obtaining an obvious error in the scale as the prices are well above $800. Any idea?
plotly.express was imported as px
plotly.graph_objects was imported as go

Comment: maybe first check what values you use in every plot. maybe one of then has different scale. You could also try to plot single `Scatter` or only `Candlestick` to see if it also has this problem.

Comment: I tried that and the problem is apparent using Candlestick, I read some old issues between matplotlib and datetime64. If I remove the tail() function everything works. It seems that tail(n) does not select the index properly and matplotlib defaults to the first n records it finds to plot. Pure conjecturing on my part.

Comment: maybe you should first get `data = df.tail(...)` and later work only with this part - `x=data.index, y=data['Open']`

Comment: yep it's cleaner, I'll do that for lack of a clear answer. I wanted the option to select the number of records in the parameters on the "fly". I guess I could transform the df in the function still. Thanks for your input.

Comment: I would do `px.line(df.reset_index().tail(n), x="index", ...)`